# Unable to execute ./sh file

Tags: linux

I created an shell script which will ask user an input and provide result based on that input. I have given (711) permission and assigned owner as (root:test) to that file.

I have one user gavin whos secondary group membership is of (test), still user gavin is not able to execute the file.  Please tell me what else need to be done ?

Basically i want a non root user (gavin) to just execute the file and not (read,write).

Comment: How can the interpreter execute a script and not be able to read it? 755 is what you want

Answer (score 2):

Script files *must* be readable in order to be executed, since the interpreter must read them. Making them executable only allows them to be invoked directly without specifying the interpreter (which the shebang line does).

Comment: so is there any way to prevent user from reading the file content but be able to execute it ?